# Why should wife take approval from husband before starting a vrata?

Tags: rituals, women, skanda-purana

In fourth Chapter, Purvardha, Kashikhanda of Skanda Mahapurana, Lopamudra, wife of sage Agastya explains the characteristics of an ideal wife. In one of the shlokas, she says as follows:

> भर्ता देवो गुरुर्भर्ता धर्मतीर्थव्रतानि च ।
>  तस्मात्सर्वं परित्यज्य पतिमेकंसमर्चयेत् ॥ ४८ ॥
>
> 48.Husband is the god, husband is the preceptor; husband alone constitutes piety, holy place and pious and observances. Hence a  woman should forsake everything and worship her husband alone.

Also there are verses which says that approval should be taken from husband before starting a vrata or any ritual.

- Why is approval necessary to do rituals for a wife?
- Why is husband considered as guru?

  ---

  <sup>Related but not a duplicate of [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14865/are-married-women-allowed-to-fast-religiouslyvrata)</sup>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Guru is who initiates a pupil into Vedas.But for a woman,the Scriptures say,  there are no Vedic initiations.

The marriage itself is regarded instead as her Vedic sacrament .

> [image]
>
> Manu Smriti 2.67. The nuptial ceremony is stated to be the Vedic sacrament for women (and to be equal to the initiation), **serving the husband
>   (equivalent to) the residence in (the house of the) teacher, and the
>   household duties (the same) as the (daily) worship of the sacred fire.**

The above portion which is highlighted explains why for any woman her husband is Guru,God and Dharma etc.

> [image]
>
> **If a woman performs a religious rite, without taking her husband's
>   consent, it is the Rakshasas who appropriate the whole of that
>   religious rite.** This is in conformity to what Manu has said.(Parashara
>   Smriti)

And, the above verse explains why a wife should always take her husband's permission before starting a Vrata.