# Who are eligible to perform Ekadashi vrata?

Tags: vishnu, women, fasting, vrata, ekadashi

Are women (married and unmarried) eligible to perform Ekadashi vrata?

Comment: What do you mean by Ekadasi vrat?

Comment: Fasting on Ekadashis and the associated vrata. @hanugm

Comment: Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14865/4732

Comment: Everyone is eligible to there is no such restriction. Exception includes ur not well and things like that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Narada purana says that anyone can perform Ekadasi Vrat. They include Brahmanas, Kshatriyas, Vaishyas, Sudras and also women

> I shall describe another Vrata well known in all the three worlds,
> which subdues all sins and which bestows all the desired benefits. O
> Brahmana, to those who perform this rite with devotion to Visnu,
> **(whether they are)** Brahmanas, or Ksatriyas, or Vaishyas or Sudras or
> **women**, it bestows salvation. It is very pleasing to Visnu. The holy
> vow called Ekddasi Vrata! (holy rite on the eleventh day) verily
> bestows everything that is desired by men. O Brahmana, it should be
> performed by all means, sinceit is very pleasing to Visnu.
>
> [[1-3, Chapter 23: The Greatness of Ekadasi Vrata, Narada Purdna]](https://archive.org/details/dli.bengal.10689.12945/page/n334/mode/1up)

Since women is mentioned explicitly, it can be inferred that there is no prohibition for either married or unmarried women. Anyone can observe this vrat.